# Comparando nomes de duas listas diferentes - ideias sobre formas de comparação

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Estou tentando fazer uma comparação de nomes de empresas entre duas listas diferentes. O caso é o seguinte: ambas as listas podem conter nomes diferentes para uma mesma empresa, por exemplo: 
Nome1: Escalar 
Nome2: Grupo Escalar 
Nome3: Escalar LTDA 
Só que eu precisaria que o algoritmo me trouxesse que são a mesma empresa. Algumas coisas que já tentei:

- Verificar, por exemplo, se o Nome1 contém no Nome2. Assim dá certo para esse caso, mas algumas empresas o segundo nome pode ser diferente (exemplo: "Escalar Participações" e "Escalar Empreendimentos"), então esse caso não se aplica. Abaixo está o código de comparação que estou usando:

  ```
   for j in range(len(bancodados["COMPANY NAME"])):
      print("j = " + str(j))
      for i in range(len(arquivo2["Nome do Cliente"])):
          p1 = re.compile(r"\b" + str(bancodados["COMPANY NAME"][j]) + r"\b", re.IGNORECASE)
          if p1.search(str(arquivo2["Nome do Cliente"][i])):
              bancodados["Contém"][j] = arquivo2["Nome do Cliente"][i]
  ```
- Como explícito no exemplo acima, também usei regex para pegar somente os nomes inteiros, e não uma parte do nome, ou seja, se eu for comparar o nome "Escalar" vai pegar "Escalar LTDA", mas não "Escalares".
- Em outros testes, usando regex, fiz o algoritmo excluir nomes como LTDA, SA, ect, assim como fazer uma dupla comparação (verificar se o Nome1 contém no Nome2, e vice-versa), na tentativa de aumentar a eficácia do algoritmo.

  Qual o objetivo com esse projeto: verificar quais empresas já pertencem a uma lista previamente definida, usando como comparação uma segunda lista de empresas. Para esse projeto, eu não posso ter na lista final empresas que existem na segunda lista. Porém, ainda tenho alguns nomes que estão presentes nas duas listas que o algoritmo não consegue detectar, que basicamente são casos de empresas com nomes compostos e diferentes, como: "Amireia Pajoara" e "Pajoara Industria e Comercio". 
  Então queria saber se alguém pode me dar um insight do que posso testar para aumentar a eficiência do algoritmo.

Comment: Procure por NLP é mais adequado ao seu caso.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu estava querendo algo um pouco mais prático e rápido, pois não tenho conhecimentos muito aprofundados de NLP. Mas agradeço de qualquer forma, e irei pesquisar sim.

Comment: Não entendi, "Amireia Pajoara" e "Pajoara Industria e Comercio" são a mesma empresa ou não? De onde vem esses nomes e como vc sabe que "Escalar", "Grupo Escalar" e "Escalar LTDA" são a mesma empresa? Em algum lugar tem essa informação, não? Talvez seja mais fácil ter, para cada empresa, uma lista de todos os nomes possíveis, assim vc compara cada nome com toda a lista (e aí nem precisaria de regex)

Comment: @hkotsubo, esses nomes seriam da mesma empresa sim. O que acontece é que a lista de comparação pode vir com uma versão do nome da empresa que ainda não mapeamos, e aí o algoritmo também não seria tão eficiente quanto usar regex. A princípio não podemos afirmar que  "Amireia Pajoara" e "Pajoara Industria e Comercio" são a mesma empresa, mas para o meu processo, é preferível que eu exclua da minha lista final ao invés de correr o risco de serem a mesma empresa.

Comment: na hora de comparar os dois dados, tentou com um `in`? Não sei se entendi ao certo, mas tive algo parecido, duas listas, eu percorria uma e utilizava o `in` para saber se existe o valor no outro. Entendeu?